How many miles/km of tunnels would be required to replace all airports in the world
Assume that we wanted to replace all air travel with underground, high speed tunnels like Hyperloop. How many miles/km of tunnels would be required?
For example, according to wikipedia there are 1200 international airports. A simple approximation would be to assume they are distributed evenly over the surface of the earth, then a complete graph would have n(n-1)/2 links, each equal to the average distance between the 1200 airports.
Ideally, the total mileage for direct routes from all airports of the world could be summed based on a map like this. But the underlying data is hard to find in a usable form.
Is there a more sophisticated way to estimate this and get data sources or is this already summarized the total air-miles for typical flights connecting the airports of the world?

that calculation assumes direct flights from any international airport to all other international airports. Even with airplanes that can fly anywhere this isn't done. LHR only connects to 214 destinations..

Have a look at the international telegraph network in the Victorian era. This connected Australia to the UK, to the USA. The longest links challenged the technology of the day, just as hyper loop tunnels would challenge us today. There may be some parts of the world that are not connected, but it ought to give an idea of what the network outline should be. Aircraft can travel any route between nodes. Telegraph and trains have to take a fixed route, so expect large trunk lines between continents, and more branch lines to other places.

If assuming all current international airports are connected, then calculating the minimum spanning tree would give the lower bound. Complete graph would be an extreme upper bound that would never be reached.

"But the underlying data is hard to find in a usable form." Try search terms "latitude and longitude for airports" I found a csv pretty quick that seemed to have sufficient info.

The routes from airport to airport are the challenge.

VTC - Fundamentally this is not a World Building question. It is either a Maths question or it is an Engineering question. It's a great Question - although the premise has a World Building element, the Answer is not a world building answer.

just FYI You can't run tunnels under the ocean, there are volcanoes in the way.

This is a Frame Challenge
The only way for this to make any sense is for the tunnels to allow faster and more convenient transport than the equivalent airborne transport.
Unfortunately, we must assume you're not tunneling through the inner core of the planet. In fact, we're assuming you're not tunneling through the cores at all, just the mantle. The problem with the cores are the heat, the pressure, the fact that they're moving (in fact the inner core is spinning quite a bit faster than the mantle).
That means you're not really saving a ton of distance — but you are saving some. But I'm not done with problems.
Tunnels are great when they don't pass through seismically active zones — but your solution won't have that privilege. That means either going around seismic zones (which might not be possible) or developing technology that can withstand them. If we're going to invest your world with that much Clarkean magic, then the question is moot. Replace every air route (no matter how small) with a tunnel and you're done. The question becomes a simple, "what's the total distance traveled if you moved along every airborne route once?" Multiply by some reasonable guess like 0.8 to remove the distance difference between over and under ground and you're done.
Finally, there's one thing you're really ignoring. When an airplane flies, air compresses a bit but moves out of the way. When a train travels, there's a lot more compression because there's a lot fewer places the air can go. Even if you try to accommodate this, you're either relying on Clarkean magic to deal with continent- and ocean-spanning routes, or you're living with the reduction in speed caused by air compression.
And to make a point, the fastest bullet train is the Shanghai Maglev travels 460 km/h. That's impressive! But your average trans-ocean flight is about 900 km/h.
And that, all by itself, is why I'm posting a frame challenge. I could suspend my disbelief if all local airplane routes were replaced by high speed underground rail. I might even suspend my disbelief concerning many/most intracontinental routes.
But I can't suspend my disbelief for transoceanic flights or polar flights. There's no number or length of tunnels that can overcome a nearly 2X travel speed. Unless you invoke Clarkean magic to move your trains at least 750-850 km/h (you don't need to match it as you don't need to sink below the Earth's surface as much as planes must rise above it).
BTW: There might be a benefit to your plan. There are a fair number of wonky plane routes due to airspace restrictions and, occasionally, weather restrictions. I think I could suspend my disbelief that you wouldn't have any of those with tunnels. Of course, if you blow up a plane all you do is kill a few hundred people and destroy one plane. If you blow up a train you likely bring the entire route to an absolute standstill, similar to any number of Suez canal blockages only worse. But those are issues that are more valuable for your story than they are valuable for worldbuilding.
One last thing: there may be no practical answer to your question, even if we simplify it with Clarkean magic. As of 2014 (yeah, ten years ago) there were more than 60,000 flight routes in the world. Simply duplicating them would economically ruin the planet. Creating an efficient set of tunnels to replace them functionally would be a PhD thesis amount of work. And I might be underestimating the amount of work. In short, I think you need to give up your quest for a number and move forward with a narrative reference to something like the UN global transoceanic subterrestrial transportation initiative, a phrase that sounds sufficiently grand that people "get it."

By the way, I took your question's phrase, "all airports" seriously. There are over 40,000 airports with International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) codes. There are probably 200,000 airports that don't include "we just have people land over in that field" bush locations. All airports is a pretty tall order.

Great response. This question was to get the data to estimate where a civilization would need to be on the Kardashev scale to take on a similar mega project. I'm doing the 1st order engineering calculations to estimate the amount of energy required to build and the power required to maintain such a system. The extreme of replacing all air routes with tunnels has a goal akin to decoupling mankind's presence from the eco-systems (land, sea, air) as much as possible.
BTW, Travel speeds as faster than airplanes could be achieved by depressurizing the tunnels.

Note that you can get to and even above typical airplane speed with a maglev train system if you put into a vaccum tunnel. This technology is currently in experimental stage on earth right now, https://www.iflscience.com/chinas-hyperloop-breaks-own-speed-record-hitting-over-623-kilometers-per-hour-72860 so this is nowhere near Clarkean magic. If we had the technology to build 1000s of kilometers of tunnels at some feasible economic price, pumping the air out of them would be a trivial addon.

@quarague That's a good point and a great reference - but "if we had the technology..." implies Clarkean magic. My biggest concern (stated in the answer) is dealing with a moving geology. As stated, I think as a local solution (eliminating regional flights) it's very believable. But globally, it would need some magic like adamantium walls and unobtainium-based power distribution. Frankly, handwaving isn't bad - science fiction does it all the time.

@JBH, the question was frames to facilitate calculating the amount of energy required to  move the geology and maintain the system. It gets at what would you do with a Type I civilization power level.

That depends on the traffic patterns.
If I were to travel from Hennigsdorf, Brandenburg, Germany to Randolph, New Jersey, USA, I might take a tram to the train station, a regional train to the airport, the plane to some airport in or near New York, and a rental car from that airport to my destination. That's assuming I don't get a layover on my flight, which would add another airport.
With express trains, even very fast ones, I would probably get many more stops and connections on the "main" leg of the journey. Getting a plane to travel altitude eats a lot of energy. Traveling more miles once it is up is comparatively cheap. My expectation as an express train traveler would be that I get more connections than with a plane, but in compensation I'd expect the stations to be more conveniently located. The patterns of intermodal transport change. Car or cab or mass transit to the train station, a sequence of trains, then mass transit or cab or car.
Earth has 150 million km2 of land area. Assume that there is an express train station every 100 km, and for simplification put them on a grid pattern. 15000 stations in total, and 3 million km of lines. (This grid would mean at most 70 km to the next station, to be covered by individual cars, or mass transit. In practice, the land will not be evenly covered. More lines and stations in urbanized areas, fewer in rural areas.)
As a reality check, I'm getting 1 km of rail for every 50 km2 of area. The EU does better than that, counting all rail, while the US has about that much. We'd probably talking about additional tunnels, not a replacement of the current lines.

The road density is a good sanity check. That is available on these table - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_road_network_size
The US is 72 km of roads per 100 sq km.
France and Germany are about 200 km of roads per sq km.

The US is, as always, mostly empty space.

Approximation
I presume that something that resembles a train network rather then lots of direct routes. Eg Berlin to Chicago would Likely involve a route that would include London perhaps Toronto.
Method
I found a list of airports, pruned it to to the 4087 that were marked as 'large'
Brought the file into QGIS.
Upper reasonable bound would be computing the Delaunay triangles for all 4k airports and then computing edge lengths. But the over seas connections are excessive. eg six ocean connections from South America to South Africa. For whatever reason the numbers were too big, so not including them.
Computed the minimum spanning tree (MST) after some hassles.
That gave 202 Mm
More complete answer
For more complete/expected answer I would add in the Delaunay triangulation for all airports of each continent. Ideally only for those within a continent to reflect land connections are easier/cheaper then deep water.
Estimate of complete
Estimate of the complete answer that would be closer to replacing all air routes.
Could add in a Delaunay triangulation for sets of airports within a continent to the MST and calculating that distance, but that would be several steps.
So guesstimating that doubling the MST value would provide enough additional routes that allow for higher efficiency without too much extra cost. Maybe need to triple to account for actual lines will not be strait.
Conclusion
So 400 Mm of tunnels/tracks double the MST is a plausible amount of track to provide connections between the ~4k large airports of the world. (about 10 trips around the equator.)
